# How to redirect user to different page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make to redirect the user to another page, in accordance to the language of the browser. For example: if the language of the browser `english` redirect to `site.com/en/`.

I try to do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;

    switch (userLang) {
        case 'en':
            window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/en';
            break;
        case 'de':
            window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/de';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

It's works but the page is constantly reloaded. How to solve it or prompt another solution?

Comment: How could this work if userLang output is en-US?

Comment: inside the default case log the value of userLang and correct the cases based on that value.

Comment: OP, as an aside, I wouldn't endeavor to do this on the client at all. This should be done on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page is constantly reloaded as you're not checking whether the user is already on the correct language site.

On your pages you could store a javascript variable for the pages language produced server-side. For example:

```
var thisLanguage = 'en';
```

Then change your javascript logic to take this into account and only apply the redirect if the user's language is different to `thisLanguage`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;

    if (userLang != thisLanguage){

       switch (userLang) {
           case 'en':
               window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/en';
               break;
           case 'de':
               window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/de';
               break;
           default:
               break;
       }

    }
});
```

Comment: When it's `de`, it'll hit the switch, redirect to `/de`, then it'll reload the page, and do the same again. It'll still loop. And what's the point in your first case? It'll never hit that first case.

Comment: @JayMee that's why `thisLanguage` depends on server side construction

Comment: On the `/de` page there will be a variable of `var userLanguage = 'de'` and therefore this will match the current `userLang` and won't redirect. Am I missing something?

Comment: You've just edited it to add 'produced server-side', it now makes sense. That wasn't clear in the first instance so I thought you meant you were hard-coding `en`.

Comment: The fact you've suggested a server-side implementation (of sorts) gets my upvote. This shouldn't be done solely on the client.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should detect the language by reading it from the URL, since you want to redirect the users to appropriate URL:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var languageSuffix = window.location.pathname;
    if(languageSuffix !== '/') {
        return;
    }

    var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;

    switch (languageSuffix) {
        case '/en':
            window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/en';
            break;
        case '/de':
            window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/de';
            break;
       default:
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can check if the url is same as current url something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
    var urlToRedirect = '';

    switch (userLang) {
        case 'en':
            urlToRedirect = window.location.origin + '/en';
            break;
        case 'de':
            urlToRedirect = window.location.origin + '/de';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if(urlToRedirect!=='' && urlToRedirect!==window.location.href){
       window.location.href = urlToRedirect;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = $(location).attr('href');
    var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;

    if(url.indexOf("/en") == -1 && userLang == 'en') {
        window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/en';
    } else if (url.indexOf("/de") == -1 && userLang == 'de'){
        window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/de';
    } else {
        // Do nothing
    }
});
```